# iOS Swift NSURL Web Address Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I'm attempting to get data from a server.  My URL is (for example): http://dommain.com/action

When I execute

```
let nsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)
```

the URL gets translated into http:/domain.com/action. Then when I execute this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL) {
    (data, response, error) in
    print("data=\(data) response=\(response) error=\(error)")
}
```

the error property says it can't find "file:///http:/domain.com/action

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Read the docs for `NSURL fileURLWithPath` and the issue will be clear.

Comment: I did look at the docs first but didn't find the answer.  However, now that I know what the answer is it was quite clear in the docs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
let nsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)
```

with

```
let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
```

> An NSURL object represents a URL that can potentially contain the location of a resource on a remote server, the path of a local file on disk, or even an arbitrary piece of encoded data.

`NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)` initializes and returns a newly created NSURL object as a **file** URL with a specified path. For network URL use `NSURL(string: url)` instead.

---

For Swift 3 and upwards, use [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) instead of `NSURL`:

```
let u = URL(string: url)
```

Comment: I was trying that only I was doing let nsurl = NSURL(String: url).  I wasn't using a lowercase string!  Thanks!